# Is spaCy supporting custom types for Named Entity Recognition?

Tags: spacy

In the documentation of the '*Named Entity Recognition*' feature of spaCy (https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities)
the documentation states that spaCy can recognize 'various types' of named entities such as 'PERSON', 'LOC', 'PRODUCT' (https://spacy.io/api/annotation#named-entities).

My question is: can I also train data with my custom entities? For example I would like to train invoice data to regognize for example IBAN / BIC or an invoice no. . Is this also possible or is this feature restricted to a fixed list of entities only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does support custom entities, cf [this section](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-new-entity-type) titled "Training an additional entity type".

For example, to add a label called `MY_ANIMAL`, you can use training data like such:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    (
        "Horses are too tall and they pretend to care about your feelings",
        {"entities": [(0, 6, MY_ANIMAL)]},
    ),
    ("Do they bite?", {"entities": []}),
    (
        "horses are too tall and they pretend to care about your feelings",
        {"entities": [(0, 6, MY_ANIMAL)]},
    ),
]
```

And feed that into either an existing NER model as additional training, or a newly created NER pipe.

However, a caveat: the ML model is optimized for recognizing named entities, which are usually capitalized nouns like "John", "London" or "The Times". You can also try to train it on more generic things like numbers, but it may not work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I missed. I also understand your thoughts about 'usually capitalized nouns' . But on the other hand in the examples there are also entities like PERCENT, DATE and TIME. Should not be an IBAN similar to that kind of data?

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please mark it as such ;-) And yes, you're right that there are also "non-typical" entities in the pretrained models. My take is that you can definitely give it a try to train an NER on your IBAN numbers etc, but I just wanted to added a word of caution. But as is common in ML/NLP, you'll just have to try it out and see :-)